# Embedding attributes from a many-to-one relationship

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, many-to-one

Given the `COUNTRIES` and `REGIONS` tables from [Oracle Database HR sample schema](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/diagrams.htm#COMSC112):

```
COUNTRIES(country_id, country_name, region_id)
REGIONS(region_id, region_name)
```

And this `Country` entity class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRIES")
public class Country {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

I would like to map both tables within a single `Country` entity class, that is, without creating a separate `Region` entity class.

Instead of this many-to-one relationship:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "REGION_ID")
private Region region;
```

I would like to have a simple `String regionName` attribute mapped to `REGIONS.REGION_NAME`, using `REGIONS.REGION_ID = COUNTRIES.REGION_ID` as the join condition.

Is this kind of mapping supported in JPA 2.0? Which annotations should I use?

Comment: You mean you want a SecondaryTable for Region? why not read JPA docs for secondary tables? Internet search reveals plenty

Comment: I don't think t you can use @SecondaryTable with non-PK join which is what you'd have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you can't use `@SecondaryTable` with a non-PK join which is what you'd have here i.e. the tables do not share the same PK.

The simplest (and probably only) option I can see then is to create a view on the DB and map an Entity to that:

```
create view vw_countries as
select 
    c.country_id as id, c.country_name as name, r.region_name as region
from 
    countries c
inner join 
    regions r on r.region_id = c.region_id
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vw_countries")
public class Country{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String region;
}
```